# How do I calculate the average direction of two vectors

Tags: iphone, math, vector

I am writing an opengl based iphone app and would like to allow a user to translate around a view based on the direction that they move two fingers on the screen. For one finger I know I could just calculate the vector from the start position to the current position of the users finger and then find the unit vector of this to get just the direction, but I don't know how I would do this for two fingers, I don't think adding the components of the vectors and calculating the average would work so I'm pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Vector math works just like you think:

```
v3 = (v1 + v2) / 2
```

Is equivalent to:

```
v3.x = (v1.x + v2.x) / 2;
v3.y = (v1.y + v2.y) / 2;
v3.z = (v1.z + v2.z) / 2;
```

Answer (score 10):

Usually it is better to multiply than divide for speed reasons when doing graphics programming so I would recommend this:

v3 = (v1 + v2) * 0.5f;

Comment: Wouldn't stuff like this get optimized by the compiler, so `/ 2.0` is the same as `* 0.5`?

Comment: Yes it should, at least from my experience with typical C compilers. It's another story if you have a variable which is constant over let's say a longer loop in which you divide something by it. Then I can measure differences if you calculate a new variable (the inverse) and multiply in the loop. Optimizing compilers are fairly quickly improving though.

Answer (score 8):

If you are only interested in the direction, You should add them and normalize the result vector,

```
(v1 + v2)/abs(v1 + v2)
```

Comment: if only interested in the direction, the v1 and v2 must be normalized first.

Comment: Is that a component-wise division?

Answer (score 5):

Easy thought experiment: Do it for unit vectors in x and y direction.  Intuitively you can picture that the "average" would be a unit vector at a 45 degree angle up and to the right.  That's exactly what happens.  The thought experiment suggests that you need to normalize the average by its magnitude to get a unit vector.  I'd advise that you do so.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but this is wrong. In vector world a "mean" in the sense of averaging components means nothing. Imagine (-1 0) and (1 0) -> average = 0 0 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

it's not as easy as it might look: you have to use slerp-interpolation to find the half arc on the unit sphere: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp 
In depth here: http://www.essentialmath.com/index.htm

Comment: Technically yes, but for unit vectors, Slerp with equal weights reduces to a simple mean + normalization.

Comment: And if you’re going to normalize in the end anyway, then just normalized(a+b) is fine. No need to divide by two to get the mean.

Answer (score 4):

To understand it intuitively, you could draw the two vectors down. Then draw a line segment between the endpoints of the two. The midpoint of this segment is the average vector. This works for any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

adding them and dividing by two does work